# Controls keep disappearing from my JFrame, no JPanes or anything to be painted

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, jcheckbox

Here is some of my code. It should be noted that this is not my exact code as I did have much more added, but long story short, I can guarantee that none of the controls touch each other, and that they are all added to this frame. Where then is my problem. It should be noted that I am not highly experienced with this, and as such need specific help. I don't see why these are giving me problems, such as buttons being too big and out of place, but I need them in the exact location which I specify at the exact size, and never disappearing or flickering. What can I do?

```
public class TesterFrame extends JFrame{
    public TesterFrame(){
        setSize(500,500);
        JButton jb = new JButton("Button");
        jb.setLocation(100, 100);
        jb.setSize(20,20);
        JCheckBox jcb = new JCheckBox("CheckBox");
        jcb.setLocation(20,20);
        jcb.setSize(30,30);
        add(jb); add(jcb);
        JButton jb2=new JButton("BUTTON");
        jb2.setLocation(60,60);
        jb2.setSize(30,30);
        add(jb2);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can't position components like this in a border layout(default layout).

Answer (score 1):

`JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` by default, which will only allow a single component to be position at any of it's five available slots.

You're basically adding all the components to the `BorderLayout.CENTER` position, but only the last is actually be laid out.

See [How to Use BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for more details

Try calling `setLayout(new FlowLayout());` before you start adding components.

Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details and a list of other layout managers which will help you